# why is there no render() in functional components

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit confused why render is used in class components and not in functional. Within render we return jsx syntax and similarly even in functional we return jsx syntax. But why there is no render in functional components?

Comment: The function itself is the render method, except that it gets the props as the first argument instead of being able to access it at `this.props` like you do in stateful components.

Comment: See [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) for more info

Comment: i hope the result of this search will help you [diff between functional and stateful component](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=diff+between+class+and+functional+component+react+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN785IN785&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRpZaN3JTcAhXIvI8KHamfBbAQrQIIQigEMAE&biw=1440&bih=803)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function itself is the render method, except that it gets the `props` as the first argument instead of being accessible at `this.props` like it is in stateful components.

```js
function StatelessPerson(props) {
  return <h1> {props.name} </h1>;
}

class StatefulPerson extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1> {this.props.name} </h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <StatelessPerson name="Foo" />
    <StatefulPerson name="Bar" />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```